# Using Criteria object in a query builder in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have 2 query builders. One for fetching all results (paginated) and one for getting the total count.
The criteria for these query will be nearly the same, so I want to use a `Criteria` object to just attach to the query builder afterwards.

```
  $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('vo');;

  $criteria = Criteria::create();
  $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("vo.creator", $currentUser));
  $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("vo.other", $something));

  $queryBuilder->addCriteria($criteria);
```

The problem is: In the middle of a lot of ANDs I also have an OR. Just in a plain query builder it reads:

```
$criteria->andWhere('vo.public = :isPublic OR vo.offerID IN (:sharedOfferIDs)');
```

Using Laravel Eloquent, you could beautifully do that

```
->where('vo.creator', '=', $currentUser)
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
         query->where('vo.public ', '=', true)
              ->where('vo.offerID', 'in', [3, 4]');
        })
```

To be even clearer, I want the result SQL to be something like:

```
where vo.creator = $currentUser AND (vo.public = true OR vo.offerID in [3, 4])
```

How can I archive this using Doctrine `Criteria`?

Comment: did you try `$criteria->andWhere(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$array = [3, 4];
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('vo');
$queryBuilder->where('vo.creator = :creator')
             ->andWhere('vo.public = true OR vo.offerID IN (:array) ')
             ->setParameter('creator', $currentUser)
             ->setParameter('array', $array);
```